# How to implement images slider with caption using bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have w page built with bootstrap to be responsive, the first part of the website contain an images slideshow with caption as the following structure

```
<div class="row carousel slide" id="main-slider" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img class="slide-image" src="..."/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="slide-image" src="..."/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="slide-image" src="..."/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
              <p>caption1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <p>caption2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <p>caption2</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the problem is, after the first round of auto slider, the caption disappear (the class active removed), but the image slider works good and does not stop.

link of example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/c5md6bw4/)

how could i solve this problem ? is there anyway to do that with carousel and keep it responsive ?[image]

Comment: js fiddle might help us to solve it quick

Comment: i did it as possible , http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/c5md6bw4/

Comment: Why do you have *two* carousels (carousel-inner)? Don't you just want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c5md6bw4/1/

Comment: no i don't want the caption under the photo, look at the image in the question, it is responsive in full width mode the image will be next to caption, and in mobile mode the caption under the image slide. @aquinas

Comment: i think you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/c5md6bw4/4/

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-extended-320-compatible

Just remove the thumbs.

Comment: thank you @Aibrean , that is what i want exactly !